# Why can I assign to [], but not () in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

Why is the second statement a syntax error, while the first is not?

```
>>> [] = ()
>>> () = []
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to ()
```

Comment: Cause tuples are immutable? Right? Not sure.

Comment: That was my first thought. But why can you assign to an empty list?

Comment: @Jason: You can do `(a,b) = [1,2]`. This assigns `a=1` and `b=2`.